# Using default application timezone with DateTime.strptime in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I read similar questions but did not find a solution.

My Rails 5 App is in

> 'America/Sao_Paulo'

time zone but saves all times in UTC to the database.

When saving a datetime

> '2017-01-01 19:00:00'

to my database it will convert it to UTC and save the UTS time to the database.

Now I need to convert a string to datetime using:

```
DateTime.strptime(date + ' ' + time, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

And this will take the date and time values as they are and save them to the database without converting to UTC. How can I let my app know that my the datetime is not in UTC yet?

Comment: It's not a "default way", so it won't fit as a proper solution. But I had the same issue and solved by `DateTime.strptime("#{str} #{Time.now.zone}", '%Y-%m-%d %Z')`

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord (by default) will save any datetime to UTC. So, in my opinion you don't need to worry if the time in the database isn't yet in UTC, because ActiveRecord will convert it to UTC.

So, when saving to database, ActiveRecord will always convert it to UTC (whether it is in UTC or not).

And when fetching from database, it follows your configuration in `config/application.rb`

You can find in the file `config.time_zone = 'YOUR_TIMEZONE'`.

Reference:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html

Hope it helps, cheers!